# how fix error java.lang.StackOverflowError cause by must probabuly relation @ManytoMany

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have relation ManytoMany with table associations. But I have error StackOverflowError. I find is this relation case my problem. So I tried to use the option (fetch = FetchType.LAZY) but I think is not work.

```
2021-05-31 16:10:54.417 ERROR 19188 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
```

```java
@Entity
public class Document implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_file")
    private FileDB file;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_doc_type")
    private DocumentType type;
    private Date documentDate;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "document_codominium_associations",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "id_document" ),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "id_codominium" ) )
    private List<Condominium> lstCodiminium;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "document_coowner_associations",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "id_document" ),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "id_coowner" ) )
    private List<CoOwner> lstCoOwner;
}
@Entity
public class Condominium implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private Byte[] picture;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String description;
    private float percentage;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "document_codominium_associations",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "id_codominium" ),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "id_document" ) )
    private List<Document> lstDocument;
}
```

Comment: in each Document, you have a list of Condominium elements, and in each Condominium, you have a list of Document elements. that's bound to get you into trouble

Comment: Oh I thank you it's so helpful

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue before.

This happens when you have multiple @ManyToMany mappings in a class with EAGER fetch option.

There are multiple ways to solve this like changing list collection to set or making one of the fetch type to LAZY etc.

But the recommended way to solve this has been given in this article.

https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/